# Completing a disjoined parts of a captcha binary image using Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I need to fill the disjoined parts of the image with white pixels. For instance : the disjoined part in the 'o' in the top left and the one in the middle of m.[image]

My algorithm has to process thousands of images. So this is just an example of a captcha. The reason I need to do that for, is that I need to compute the vertical hough lines. But if there are disjoined parts I couldn't have all the hough lines (the line in the middle of 'm' for example).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please upload your current code in a [mcve], if you already have any. As it stands it is Too Broad, since there are lots of possibilities to do what you require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mathematical morphology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology) may be a simple way to do what you want. For example you could try dilate and then erode (this is also known as closing). If you have the image processing toolbox you can achieve that by using the matlab function [bwmorph](http://au.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html).

Example of use:

```
BW2 = bwmorph(BW,'close');
```